# How to write to a file in linux upon a condition

Tags: bash, shell

This might be so simple but I need to do this:

I have a file name `a.sh`, and it contains few lines as below

```
# firstname banuka
firstcolor green
lastname jananath
# age 25
```

And I want to write `firstname banuka` to this file, so it would look like

```
echo "firstname banuka" > a.sh
```

**BUT, before writing `firstname banuka` I want to check if file already has that value (or line)**

As you can see in the file content of `a.sh`, the part we are going to write (`firstname banuka`) can be already there but with a comment.

```
So if it has a comment,
   1. I want to un-comment it (remove `#` in front of `firstname banuka`)
```

```
If no comment and no line which says `firstname banuka`,
   2. Add the line `firstname banuka`
```

```
If no comment and line is already there,
   3. skip (don't write `firstname banuka` part to file)
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I can write to the file like this `echo "firstname banuka" > a.sh` but that's all I could achieve

Comment: `>` will clear the file you probably mean `>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string="firstname banuka"
file=./a.sh

grep -qwi "^[^[:alnum:]]*$string$" "$file" && \
sed -i "s,\(^[^[:alnum:]]*\)\($string$\),\2,i" "$file" || \
printf "\n%b\n" "$string" >> "$file"
```

Comment: except for CRLF line endings (because `$` only catches `\n` linefeed)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a programming language that can scan for patterns, has variables, and has conditional contructs. awk is one such language:

```sh
awk -v text="firstname banuka" '
    $0 ~ text {
        found = 1          # remember that we have seen it
        sub(/^ *# */, "")  # remove the comment, if there is one
    }
    {print}
    END {if (!found) {print text}}
' file
```

This will not edit the file, just print it out. With GNU awk, if you want to edit the file in-place:

```sh
gawk -i inplace -v text="..." '...' file
```

With plain bash you would write

```sh
found=false
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" == *"firstname banuka"* ]]; then
        found=true
        if [[ "$line" =~ ^[[:blank:]]*[#][[:blank:]]*(.+) ]]; then
            line="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        fi
    fi
    echo "$line"
done < file
$found || echo "firstname banuka"
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't write to the file. and I added `$found || echo "firstname banuka" >> test.txt`, but it doesn't un-comment the text if it has already in the file commented.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Bash implementation

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

found=false
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^([[:blank:]]*[#][[:blank:]]*)?(firstname banuka) ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        found=true
    else
      echo "$line"
    fi
done < a.txt
$found || echo "firstname banuka"
```

Comment: This doesn't work when there is a commented `firstname banuka`, if it is commented I want to uncomment it

Comment: @user13456401 insert a `typeset -p BASH_REMATCH` before `echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"`; and check the output. I suspect you are not using Bash but zsh instead. This is for Bash only.